# Plotting random subset of individual quadratic growth curves in R from lme or lmerMod object?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4, nlme, sjplot

I would like to plot a random subset of 10 individual's quadratic growth curves from lme4 or nlme in R using either ggplot2 or sjPlot. I know how to do this for a linear line, but not a quadratic one. Obviously the plot below with 105 participants is too crazy.

My model:

```
growthquadsl <- lmer(count~time_point+I(time_point^2) + (1+time_point|ParticipantID),
                 REML = TRUE,
                 data = longfix)
summary(growthquadsl)
    Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
    Formula: count ~ time_point + I(time_point^2) + (1 + time_point |  
        ParticipantID)
       Data: longfix
```

Output:

```
REML criterion at convergence: 23004.3

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.3234 -0.6165 -0.0802  0.5312  4.2995 

Random effects:
 Groups        Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 ParticipantID (Intercept) 28228422 5313.0        
               time_point    209490  457.7   -0.40
 Residual                  18922159 4350.0        
Number of obs: 1157, groups:  ParticipantID, 107

Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)     14242.57     605.82  23.510
time_point        874.18     157.42   5.553
I(time_point^2)   -73.47      14.75  -4.979

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) tm_pnt
time_point  -0.510       
I(tm_pnt^2)  0.355 -0.923
```

All curves:

```
ggplot(longfix, aes(x=time_point, y=count)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = predict(growthquadsl, level=1, group=ParticipantID), colour = factor(ParticipantID)), size = 1)
```

Output:

[Graph all 105 participants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMFQN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can't test this without some data but you can sample the data frame and plot all participants in that sample.

```r
# With `modelr::add_predictions`, if it works correctly for your type of model
longfix %>%
  sample_n(100) %>%
  modelr::add_predictions(fit) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time_point, y = pred)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = factor(growthquadsl)), size = 1)

# Otherwise create a column with the predictions explicitly
longfix %>%
  sample_n(100) %>%
  mutate(pred = predict(fit, newdata = .)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time_point, y = pred)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = factor(growthquadsl)), size = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
library(ggeffects)
pr <- ggpredict(growthquadsl, c("time_point", "ParticipantID [sample=10]"), type = "re")
plot(pr)
```

See [this vignette](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/randomeffects.html) for a more comprehensive explanation with examples, and [this vignette](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/effectsatvalues.html) how to plot marginal effects at specific values (e.g., for a random subsample of n=10, like in the above example).